# Xcode6-Beta Swift Playground stopped interpreting commands in any project

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

[image]

This is a brand new project with a brand new playground file created. The playground just stopped working completely.

I have read other stack overflow questions about this that point to the assistant editor to check for error. I have none.

I then clicked Editor Menu at the top and found that the Reset Playground button was greyed out and unclickable.

What has happened? I cannot use the playground at all on this machine. Any new project I open and try to use the playground it never evaluates. And I don't see any errors and the Reset Playground command is greyed out.

Also when I close the project and reopen it, Nothing prints out in the sidebar.

Please help! I am stuck and have no clue what to do.

Thanks

Comment: You don't happen to be using a core 2 duo based machine do you. At this time there are a lot if issues with playgrounds, personally I have switched back to just typing examples in the editor and doing a quick compile, just until Apple fix some of the bugs.

Comment: I am using an i3 processor which I think is quite similar to the core 2 duo. Maybe that is the issue. It's so unfortunate I was looking for to using the playground, and it stopped working in all project immediately from the start

Comment: Yup.. a lot of problems with playground. It crashed every few minutes on my laptop. I only use project to play with the syntax for now.

Comment: You have quit and restarted Xcode, right? And the machine?

Comment: Yah I tried doing that multiple times. I have XCode6-beta also installed on my new macbook pro and it works well on that machine. But it does not want to work on my iMac from mid 2010. I am thinking it might have to do with the computer itself. Apple should rectify the problem once the final is released.

Comment: Does `xcrun swift -l` on the command line work? That might help to diagnose if it's Xcode acting up or the actual Swift compiler. Have you checked Console when starting up Xcode and/or creating a playground? Any interesting messages? Did you try rebooting? Some necessary service may be acting up, somewhere.

Comment: I have been getting a lot of "SourceKitService terminated, Editor function temporarily limited" messages, sometimes just before Xcode crashes. The last time this msg appeared Xcode crashed and now none of my playgrounds will execute. Rebooting had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `import UIKit` back to `import Cocoa` - I've had better luck with the Cocoa framework in playgrounds.

Comment: just tried that and no luck. I also tried opening playground from the XCode new menu, that just open the playground without the whole development environment, which has import Cocoa as default. No luck still is not evaluating any lines of code.

Comment: I dont think the problem is related to framework. The playground is just very unstable for now.

Comment: Bear in mind that the Cocoa/UIKit import should match the playground type you've created (can be changed for an existing playground in Xcode's File Inspector)